# Which encryption mode ECB, CBC, CFB

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

My php script and my c# application will pass a hash string to each other that is 32 chars long, what is the best mode for this? I thought ECB but am unsure as it says if using more then 1 block dont use. How do I know how big the block is?

They will occasionally pass a large text file, which would be the best mode for encrypting this...CBC?

Any good useful reads welcome...

Thanks

Comment: The choice of the hash function depends on what you want to achieve by exchanging hash codes. Please elaborate.

Comment: The hash is a number. The reason its hashed because its a ID stored in a database. I hashed it so all IDs have the same length is DB.

Comment: `I hashed it so all IDs have the same length...` If that is your sole purpose in hashing (which I doubt), then you wouldn't care about any of the cryptographic characteristics of the hash. Ask yourself: Rather than hashing, would padding the numerical ID with leading zeros satisfy my purpose?   Also, there appear to be a second purpose to hashing when you mention the encryption of large text files.  (BTW, for large text files CBC is a slam dunk over EBC, of course).

Comment: @ mjv Thanks for the comments...CBC it is then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECB is the simplest mode and really not recommended (it's not quite as secure as other modes).

Personally I'd use CBC.

Comment: Can you please elaborate reasons why do you prefer CBC instead of others, e.g. CFB? Is it more secure, or does it have better performance?

Answer (score 2):

One problem of ECB (among many other problems) is that it encrypts deterministically. That is each time you encrypt the same ID, you get the same ciphertext. Thus this mode does not prevent traffic analysis. An attacker may not be able to learn the IDs that are encrypted. However, he can still determine when and how frequently the same ID is sent.

CBC and OFB when used properly use a new random IV for each encryption thus encrypting the same ID differently each time. Since you also make sure that all IDs have the same length the result should ciphertexts where the attacker cannot distinguish repeating IDs from non-repeating ones.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to Accipitridae's Answer. You would need to supply the IV to the decryption procedure. That will also be a overhead in case of CBC or OFB.